# Why is joining a clan important?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm currently in a clan and I'm thinking of leaving it because I'm unable to be active. If I leave the said clan, what features of the game will I be missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not being in a clan significantly limits what you can do in the game as the game is mainly based around you being in a clan, hence the name. Without a clan:

- You will not be able to receive troop or spell donations to fill your clan castle which increases your attacking strength nor will you be able to donate spells or troops which give you experience (which isn't very important) and achievements (which reward you with gems).
- You will not be able to take part of clan wars which have good loot (gold, elixir, dark elixir) rewards if you and your clan do well.
- You will not be able to take part in clan games which have good loot rewards and also give powerful magic items such a troop enhancers and items to instantly finish certain upgrades and researches.

However, that being said you can still farm and collect resources and upgrade your base without being in a clan, it just will take longer as your don't have the extra resources from being in a clan.

Comment: Do I still going to receive the daily 5 star attack bonus loot even I'm not in a clan?

Comment: @AkagiLeonel yes you will still receive that and you will get rewards for any non-clan event

Comment: To an extent there is a social element as well. Being able to ask for advice and chat with other clan members..... should be better than general chat.